# Acceleration event horizon

Tags: general-relativity, acceleration, event-horizon

Many introductions to General Relativity talk about the equivalence of gravity and acceleration.

Can the interesting properties of a black hole — event horizons, Hawking radiation, etc. — be produced by non-gravitational acceleration?

(I don't think this is a duplicate — searching shows me questions *about* the acceleration *at* an event horizon and this is almost the opposite).

Comment: [Wikipedia says yes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_horizon#Apparent_horizon_of_an_accelerated_particle).

Comment: An accelerated frame is in a Rindler wedge spacetime with horizons that behave similarly to black hole horizons. This Unruh radiation is observable only on the accelerated frame, but a mass interacting with this will heat up. The hot mass on an accelerated frame can be observed by an inertial observer.